# Getting an error when compiling with RenderScript library: llvm-rs-cc.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741515

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, renderscript

As the title mentions, when I want to add RenderScript to my project, I get the following error (on Gradle Sync):

Error:Execution failed for task '**:app:compileDebugRenderscript**'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Dries\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\23.0.1**llvm-rs-cc.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741515**

I'm using Android Studio 1.3.2

This is my build.gradle:

```
    import com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dries.myocrtest"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        renderscriptTargetApi 22
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile project(':tesstwo')
    compile project(':fileExplorer')
}
```

**tesstwo build.gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets{
        main{
            jni.srcDirs=[]
        }
    }
}
```

**fileExplorer build.gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Additional errors referred to in my comment on Stephen Hines' post:

```
warning: Linking two modules of different data layouts: 'C:\Users\Dries\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\23.0.1\renderscript\lib\bc\armeabi-v7a\libclcore.bc' is 'e-m:e-p:32:32-i64:64-v128:64:128-a:0:32-n32-S64' whereas 'C:\Users\Dries\AndroidDev\MyOCRTEST\app\build\generated\res\rs\debug\raw\bc64\inverse.bc' is 'e-m:e-i64:64-i128:128-n32:64-S128'
warning: Linking two modules of different target triples: C:\Users\Dries\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\23.0.1\renderscript\lib\bc\armeabi-v7a\libclcore.bc' is 'armv7-none-linux-gnueabi' whereas 'C:\Users\Dries\AndroidDev\MyOCRTEST\app\build\generated\res\rs\debug\raw\bc64\inverse.bc' is 'aarch64-none-linux-gnueabi'
E/bcc     (27612): Unable to compile the source to file C:\Users\Dries\AndroidDev\MyOCRTEST\app\build\intermediates\rs\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a\inverse.o! (Error loading input bitcode)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Dries\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\23.0.1\bcc_compat.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Failed to compile script!
```

Comment: change renderscriptTargetApi 22 to 23

Comment: thanks for the try but it's still the same error

Comment: tesstwo and fileExplorer They are compiled with what version of sdk?

Comment: I've added their build.gradle files to my post. I hope this is what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a packaging problem with the SDK. You could copy the relevant .dll files from the lib/ part of your tools installation into the bin/ directory. They should be libClang.dll, libLLVM.dll, and libbcc.dll.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I'm not sure what bin/ I have to add it too? I've tried many options like the C:\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin and the Android Studio bin but this doesn't help. When I add it to the C:\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin I get: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Dries\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\23.0.1\bcc_compat.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741515

Comment: Add it to the place where the .exe files live. Windows picks up .dll files from the executable directory just fine.

Comment: When I do that, I get the error I've written in the other comment on your post. I moved libbcinfo.dll to the executable directory and now I get the error I've added in my original post. Can you please take a look at it? EDIT: removed the         renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
from my build.gradle solved it

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, you can't use the support mode with 64-bit yet. We should have tools updates sometime soon that will allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Replace tesstwo `build.gradle` file with:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    sourceSets{
        main{
            jni.srcDirs=[]
        }
    }
}
```

**Important:**

Make sure to use gradle build tools 1.3.+

Comment: Hi Michele, thanks again for helping but I still get the same result

Comment: @DeGoosseZ which version of build tools you use?

Comment: SDK build tools: v19.1 / 23 and 23.0.1  Android SDK tools: 24.4  SDK platform-tools: 23.0.1  android support repository: rev 22  android support library: rev 23.0.1

Comment: I mean gradle Build tools..the main version is 1.3