# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript'

Tags: android, jenkins, renderscript

I'm facing issue while running the Android build in Jenkins. Not sure what is the issue.  Please help me with this.

I have installed android-sdk through the command line.

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04

I have attached the error log.

> :app:compileDebugRenderscriptwarning: Linking two modules of different
>   data layouts:
>   '/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/26.0.2/renderscript/lib/bc/armeabi-v7a/libclcore.bc'
>   is 'e-m:e-p:32:32-i64:64-v128:64:128-a:0:32-n32-S64' whereas
>   '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/android_apk_test/TestProject/app/build/generated/res/rs/debug/raw/stackblur.bc'
>   is 'e-p:32:32-i64:64-v128:64:128-n32-S64'
>
> warning: Linking two modules of different target triples:
>   /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/26.0.2/renderscript/lib/bc/armeabi-v7a/libclcore.bc'
>   is 'armv7--linux-android' whereas
>   '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/android_apk_test/TestProject/app/build/generated/res/rs/debug/raw/stackblur.bc'
>   is 'armv7-none-linux-gnueabi'
>
> warning: Linking two modules of different data layouts:
>   '/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/26.0.2/renderscript/lib/bc/x86/libclcore.bc'
>   is 'e-m:e-p:32:32-i64:64-v128:64:128-a:0:32-n32-S64' whereas
>   '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/android_apk_test/TestProject/app/build/generated/res/rs/debug/raw/stackblur.bc'
>   is 'e-p:32:32-i64:64-v128:64:128-n32-S64'
>
> warning: Linking two modules of different target triples:
>   /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/26.0.2/renderscript/lib/bc/x86/libclcore.bc'
>   is 'armv7--linux-android' whereas
>   '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/android_apk_test/TestProject/app/build/generated/res/rs/debug/raw/stackblur.bc'
>   is 'armv7-none-linux-gnueabi'

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript'.

  > A problem occurred starting process 'command '/opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/26.0.2/i686-linux-android-ld''

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108452/getting-an-error-when-compiling-with-renderscript-library-llvm-rs-cc-exe-fini

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

Since I'm working on 64-bit system, some process requires 32-bit support to get started for which I installed the following library files.

**sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386**

The above command solved the issue :)

Comment: Thanks @DDM for posting your findings. That helped me as well!